# Error with After effect Pro_FX_Presets_Particular plugin

Tags: after-effects, plugins

Does anybody know about the Pro_FX_Presets_Particular plugin? Why am I getting this error? I tried with png and jpg files. I have trapcode 15 installed. Any suggestions?

[image: Error image]

[more error images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFh3S.jpg)

Comment: you will need to provide more information. What is it you're trying to do? Did it ever work before? What have you tried? Which versions are you using?

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen with the reference video with the addon i followed all the steps. I tried with png and jpeg logo did not work with me. Im using 2018 AE. I have upload all the image that getting error with png and jpeg. I tried to convert layer to 3d yet did not get the success.